# Loop inside EOF - UNIX SCRIPTING

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I am writing a script to automatic start up of an application whenever we found error in logs.

so

```
#/bin/bash

if [ grep -c 'error' logs -eq 0 ] ;then
  exit
else

start <<EOF ## start is  a script which starts the application

7 
c
```

problem is that after running "start" , i need to enter 7 and whenever script stops with status "c-continue s-stop " ..i need to press c continuously until "start" get status run successfully.
How i can do this ?

how to insert loop inside EOF or any other way ?

Comment: If `start` doesn't read from stdin you may need to write an `expect` script

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
{ echo 7; yes c; } | start
```

Uses a [grouping construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) to allow the output of 2 commands to pipe into your script.

Comment: Assuming `start` is reading from stdin of course

Comment: If it's not, then the heredoc won't work either.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't think we know enough to say that the heredoc is in fact working

Answer (score 1):

My enhancement of [@glennjackman’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/966430/167207):

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -q 'error' logs   &&   { echo 7; yes c; } | start
```